# API no me acepta Authorization token vía Axios

Tags: axios

Tengo la siguiente instancia de Axios en el front del proeycto:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://mi_ip:9999',
  timeout: 6000
});
```

Con la siguiente petición y un `Header` de `Authorization`:

```
export const getAllRequest= (status) =>
  instance.get('/get_tweets_manual', status, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `token ${getToken()}`
    }
  });
```

He comprobado que el token sea válido cuando lo recibe, en Postman funciona con `Authorization` y Tipo: `API Key` con Key `token` y Add to `Header`.

Adjunto la respuesta del servidor, headers y error (este último se genera porque no estoy recibiendo el array de datos por la falta de autorización):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema era que el campo que recibe el token no es `Authorization`, es `token`.

```
export const getAllRequest= (status) =>
  instance.get('/get_tweets_manual', status, {
    headers: {
      'token': getToken()
    }
  });
```